# Urho3D-Blender fails to export materiall

Tags: blender

I have created a desk to use it in Urho3d, to export the blender file into compatible urho3d model I use, Urho3d-Blender extension from [this link](https://github.com/reattiva/Urho3D-Blender/blob/master/guide.txt).

The problem I am facing is, while exporting, I am just getting .mdl file, I am not getting materials and textures information file.
I have tried all permutations and combinations but have failed.
How can I use blender with urho-3d in this case?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: simply create anything add a material to it ,
when u export it with Urho3d , it should create 2 folders , namely Models and material which should be populated with .mdl and .xml respectively .
i am only getting Models folder with .mdl file , no Material folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i find the solution for this , As Blender shows this component has so many bugs , by one such bug, there were plenty of options which weren't available when i added the plug-in .

I removed the plug-in re-installed it , got those options back .
checked-in Material export and texture export .I am all set for development